# 1 array to soon issue mySQL and php

Tags: php, html

I have this strange issue with mySQL and PHP, it seems the output of the mySQL is 1 array to soon. It puts the output data from the dropdownboxes (enum) into the wrong textbox. Any help would be appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<table style="border-spacing:20px; border:2; border-color: black; border-style: solid;">
     <tr>
         <td>
            <strong>Medewerker: *</strong><br/> <?php enumDropdown(@$table_name, @medewerker) ?><br/><br/>
            <strong>Datum overboeking: </strong><br/> <input id="date" type="text" name="datum_overboeking" value="<?php echo $datum_overboeking; ?>" /><br/><br/>
            <strong>Juliette geinformeerd: </strong><br/> <?php enumDropdown(@$table_name, @juliette_geinformeerd) ?><?php echo $juliette_geinformeerd; ?> <br/><br/>
            <strong>Boekingsnummer: *</strong><br/> <input type="text" name="boekingsnummer" value="<?php echo $boekingsnummer; ?>" /><br/><br/>
            <strong>Land: </strong><br/> <?php enumDropdown(@$table_name, @land) ?><?php echo $land; ?> <br/><br/>
         </td>                 
         <td>
            <strong>Huiscode: </strong><br/> <input type="text" name="huiscode" value="<?php echo $huiscode; ?>" /><br/><br/> 
            <strong>Aanbieder: </strong><br/> <?php enumDropdown(@$table_name, @aanbieder) ?><?php echo $aanbieder; ?> <br/><br/>
            <strong>Contractvorm: </strong><br/> <?php enumDropdown(@$table_name, @contractvorm) ?><?php echo $contractvorm; ?> <br/><br/>
            <strong>Huursom: </strong><br/> <input type="text" name="huursom" value="<?php echo $huursom; ?>" /><br/><br/>
             <strong>Periode van: </strong><br/> <input id="date1" type="text" name="periode_van" value="<?php echo $periode_van; ?>" /><br/><br/>
         </td>                          
         <td>
             <strong>Periode tot: </strong><br/> <input id="date2" type="text" name="periode_tot" value="<?php echo $periode_tot; ?>" /><br/><br/>
             <strong>Distributiekanaal: </strong><br/> <input type="text" name="distributiekanaal" value="<?php echo $distributiekanaal; ?>" /><br/><br/>
             <strong>Naam klant: </strong><br/> <input type="text" name="naam_klant" value="<?php echo $naam_klant; ?>" /><br/><br/>
             <strong>Reden: </strong><br/> <?php enumDropdown(@$table_name, @reden) ?><?php echo $reden; ?> <br/><br/>
             <strong>Nieuwe boeking: </strong><br/> <?php enumDropdown(@$table_name, @nieuwe_boeking) ?><?php echo $nieuwe_boeking; ?> <br/><br/>
         </td>
         <td>
             <strong>Reden geen nieuwe boeking: </strong><br/> <?php enumDropdown(@$table_name, @reden_geen_nieuwe_boeking) ?><?php echo $reden_geen_nieuwe_boeking; ?> <br/><br/>
             <strong>Boete aanbieden: </strong><br/> <?php enumDropdown(@$table_name, @boete_aanbieden) ?><?php echo $boete_aanbieden; ?> <br/><br/>
             <strong>Administratie geinformeerd voor inhouding boete: </strong><br/> <?php enumDropdown(@$table_name, @administratie_geinformeerd_voor_inhouding_boete) ?><?php echo $administratie_geinformeerd_voor_inhouding_boete; ?> <br/><br/>
             <strong>Bedrag van boete: </strong><br/> <input type="text" name="bedrag_van_boete" value="<?php echo $bedrag_van_boete; ?>" /><br/><br/>
             <strong>Coulance HappyHome: </strong><br/> <?php enumDropdown(@$table_name, @coulance_happyhome) ?><?php echo $coulance_happyhome; ?> <br/><br/>
         </td>
     <tr>
         <td colspan="4">
             <strong>Opmerking: </strong><br/> <textarea style="width: 1000px; height: 60px;" type="text" name="opmerking" value="<?php echo $opmerking; ?>"></textarea><br/><br>
        </td>
     </tr>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

// dropdownlist met SQL values ophalen

function enumDropdown($table_name, $column_name)
{
   $table_name= 'overboekingen';   

   $selectDropdown = "<select name=\"$column_name\">";
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT COLUMN_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
   WHERE TABLE_NAME = '$table_name' AND COLUMN_NAME = '$column_name'")
   or die (mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$enumList = explode(",", str_replace("'", "", substr($row['COLUMN_TYPE'], 5, (strlen($row['COLUMN_TYPE'])-6))));

foreach($enumList as $value)
     $selectDropdown .= "<option value=\"$value\">$value</option>";

$selectDropdown .= "</select>";

    echo $selectDropdown;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

?>
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: You have to organize your code much better! Don't use the deprecated `mysql_*` extension, don't suppress warnings with an `@`, when you set a function parameter and you expect a string use quotes. Could you clearify your problem and add an image to your post of the output?

Comment: Thank you for the advise, indeed I still need to learn about PDO but at the moment I have to finish this project for school so security is not important for this application. I tryed to add an image but I need 10 rep points for that so sorry I can not post it. The problem is that the first value of the dropdownboxes are shown on the wrong element. They are being put in the element before the dropdownboxes. All dropdownboxes are having this behaviour.